# Asp.Net Mvc 4 and Entity framework 5 code first database migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I created an internet asp.net Mvc 4 application. It used EF5 code first, LocalDB by default. I have the following issues. I put all my tables in data context class `MyContext` and enabled database migration on it.

1. UsersContext. I added a field `email` in the table `UserProfile`. However, I cannot enable database migration on the default `UsersContext` since I already enabled migration on `MyContext`. I had to delete the database and let it recreate `UserProfile` table (I had to open the user register page first, otherwise it will create `UserProfile` without field `email`.)
2. I published the project to a server with IIS/Sql Server and keep working on the project. However, from time to time it shows the model of `UsersContext` were changed (not true) and I had to delete the database on the live server and let it recreate the database.
3. Sometimes it create the same index twice on a table in `MyContext` and it failed the migration. And I had to delete the database again for recreating.

How to prevent the above issues? Should database migration be disabled after go live? How to apply the Model/DB changes?

Comment: You should use only one context. See the following answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693843/entity-framework-multiple-object-contexts

Comment: The `UsersContext` was created by MVC template scaffold. Should I rename the class in `AccountModel`?